# Html.Dropdownlistfor selected value is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can't get the selected value to work with HTML.dropwdownlistfor

Here is what I have trying to get to work, ALL DATA IS THERE, the select statement finds the selected item, the ienumerable of SelectListItems has an item that has the "select = true" I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

MODEL:

```
[SitecoreIgnore]
public virtual IEnumerable<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item> List_Location { get; set; }
public virtual Sitecore.Data.Items.Item Location { get; set; }
[SitecoreIgnore]
public virtual string Location_Model { get; set; }
```

HELPER METHOD:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListConstructor(Item selectedItem, IEnumerable<Item> options)
{
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listings = from o in options
select new SelectListItem
{
Selected = (selectedItem.ID == o.ID),
Text = o.DisplayName,
Value = o.ID.ToString()
};



return listings;            
}
```

Controller: (The casting works fine, data is there)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateAdStep(Classified model)
{
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
return RedirectToAction("PreviewAd", model);
}

var allerrrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

return View(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{69040A7B-5444-4ECF-A081-C4A3B26876B5}").GlassCast<Classified>());
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateAdStep()
{
var trial = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{69040A7B-5444-4ECF-A081-C4A3B26876B5}").GlassCast<Classified>();
return View(trial);
}
```

CSHTML LINE ATTEMPTS:
1)

```
@{ var emo = CalCPA.Source.Models.Utility.Utility.SelectListConstructor(Model.Location, Model.List_Location);
var emo2 = emo.Where(i=> i.Selected == true).FirstOrDefault();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Location_Model, new SelectList(emo, "Value", "Text", emo2.Value))
```

2)

```
@{ var emo = CalCPA.Source.Models.Utility.Utility.SelectListConstructor(Model.Location, Model.List_Location);
var emo2 = emo.Where(i=> i.Selected == true).FirstOrDefault();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Location_Model, new SelectList(emo, "Value", "Text", emo2))
```

3)

```
@{ var emo = CalCPA.Source.Models.Utility.Utility.SelectListConstructor(Model.Location, Model.List_Location);
var emo2 = emo.Where(i=> i.Selected == true).FirstOrDefault();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Location_Model, emo)
```

Thanks for any insight/help!!!

Comment: show your [HttpPost]-method in Controller

Comment: Is Classified contains Location_Model field?

Comment: @IgorSemin Yeah it's right there below "Location" in my model post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your going to use `DropDownListFor` you need to set the selected value in the model first.

In your action (or model builder):

```
model.Location_Model = "my selected value";
```

Then your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Location_Model, new SelectList(emo, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: THanks! I had no idea that the SelectedValue parameter wasn't needed here. Quick question while I have you here, do you by any chance know how to use the @HTML.DropdownListFor<Classified, Item>(//params)

I tried using this however itw ould escape the razor syntax, if you could just link an example that would be great! I'mnot sure what words to google to find one

Comment: @oorosco Where are you getting that from? I dont see a `DropDownListFor()` with 2 generic parameters.

Comment: Yeah here's a snap shot of my screen, http://puu.sh/aPSMu/698c336079.png   you see the TModel, TProperty and here's some msdn stuff I found as well, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: `TModel` is the view model, cant override that.

Comment: in that case is there any example you can think of using the TPRoperty? I googled it and could not find anything for "html helper (html.dropdownlistfor) generic function" but cannot find anything

Comment: TProperty is being specified in the lambda expression. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the generic parameters?

Comment: oh ok, I was just trying to understand the syntax, so it's not a generic parameter then? I just saw it and found it weird and was trying to understand what it meant.

Comment: It is a generic parameter, but the type is specified by the lambda expression.